# node.js ejs - Don't render file if it does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a views folder structure and a ejs file profile_60113.ejs like this

```
views
    docs
        profile_60113.ejs
```

I can dynamically render the file like this (where data.groupID == 60113):

```
<%- include("docs/profile_" + data.groupID); %>
```

But how can I first check if the file exists? I tried this:

```
<% if (fs.existsSync("views/docs/profile_" + data.groupID)) { %>
    <%- include("docs/profile_" + data.groupID); %>
<% } %>
```

Or ...

```
<% if (fs.existsSync("docs/profile_" + data.groupID)) { %>
    <%- include("docs/profile_" + data.groupID); %>
<% } %>
```

But didn't work ... 
const fs = require('fs') is included in the controller and fs:fs is rendered

Comment: Can't you just check the existance of that file within your controller? Does it have to be within the ejs file?

Comment: ... yes you are right ... didn't think of that initially. Thanks!

Comment: You really should not be using `fs.existsSync()` in a server at all.  It can ruin your scalability because it blocks the one Javascript thread.  You can test for existence with asynchronous I/O before you call `res.render()` and pass in a boolean to the template and the template can use the boolean.

Comment: @jfriend00 ... thanks for the hint! ... I adjusted accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works is e.g.:

Option 1 (Synchronously): Template

Serverside:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var getGroupID = 60113;

res.render('docs', {
   page: setPage,
   data: {groupID: getGroupID},
   fs: fs   
});
```

Template:

```
<% if (fs.existsSync("views/docs/profile_" + data.groupID + ".ejs")) { %>
    <%- include("docs/profile_" + data.groupID); %>
<% } %>
```

Option 2 (Synchronously): Serverside & Template

Serverside:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var getGroupID = 60113;

var getProfile;
if (fs.existsSync("views/docs/profile_" + getGroupID + ".ejs")) {
  getProfile = true;
} else {
  getProfile = false;
}

res.render('docs', {
   page: setPage,
   data: {groupID: getGroupID},
   profile: getProfile   
});
```

Template:

```
<% if (profile) { %>
    <%- include("docs/profile_" + data.groupID); %>
<% } %>
```

Option 3 (Asynchronous I/O): Serverside & Template

Serverside:

```
...

var getProfile;
try {
  await fs.promises.access("views/docs/profile_" + getGroupID + ".ejs");
  getProfile = true;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}   

...
```